# iphone development: launching app on receiving push notification

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

In my app I can successfully receive push notifications. However, if the app is in the background, when I open the app I faced with the last state of the app. What I want is, even if the app is on background, opening the notification should relaunch the app like it is the first time the app is opening. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

In your AppDelegate you could react to the receipt of the notification and restore the application state in a way that is appropriate for your app.

For example if your main view controller is a UINavigationController and the user may have navigated down in the view hierarchy, you could just pop back to the navigation controller's rootViewController:

```
 [[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you could relaunch the app programmatically but if you open the app from a notification the

```
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:
```

from the UIApplicationDelegate gets called, then you could do there whatever you want to do